# SQL - spread previous values from one column into multiple new columns

Tags: sql, r, sql-server-2012, dplyr, pivot

I have a SQL table of Customer_ID, showing Payments by Year. The first (of many) customer appears like this:

```
 ID    Payment    Year
112          0    2004
112          0    2005
112          0    2006
112       9592    2007
112      12332    2008
112       9234    2011
112       5400    2012
112       7392    2014
112       8321    2015
```

Note that some years are missing. I need to create 10 new columns, showing the Payments in the previous 10 years, for each row. The resulting table should look like this:

```
 ID    Payment    Year   T-1  T-2  T-3  T-4  T-5  T-6  T-7  T-8  T-9 T-10   
112          0    2004  NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL
112          0    2005     0 NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL
112          0    2006     0    0 NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL
112        952    2007     0    0    0 NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL
112       1232    2008   952    0    0    0 NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL
112        924    2011  NULL NULL 1232  952    0    0    0 NULL NULL NULL 
112        500    2012   924 NULL NULL 1232  952    0    0    0 NULL NULL 
112        392    2014  NULL  500  924 NULL NULL 1232  952    0    0    0
112        821    2015   392 NULL  500  924 NULL NULL 1232  952    0    0
```

I am well aware that this is a large duplication of data, and so seems like a strange thing to do. However, I would still like to do it! (the data is being prepared for a predictive model, in which previous payments (and other info) will be used to predict the current year's payment)

I'm not really sure where to start with this. I have been looking at using pivot, but can't figure out how to get it to select values from a customer's previous year.

I would very much like to do this in SQL. If that is not possible I may be able to copy the table into R - but SQL is my preference.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `lag()` if you had full data:

```
select t.*,
       lag(payment, 1) over (partition by id order by year) as t_1,
       lag(payment, 2) over (partition by id order by year) as t_2,
       . . .
from t;
```

However, for your situation with missing intermediate years, `left join` may be simpler:

```
select t.*,
       t1.payment as t_1,
       t2.payment as t_2,
       . . .
from t left join
     t t1
     on t1.id = t.id and
        t1.year = t.year - 1 left join
     t t2
     on t1.id = t.id and
        t1.year = t.year - 2 left join
     . . .;
```

Comment: Many thanks, the "left join" solution worked well for me. If I ran all the joins in one query it would take forever, so I ended up running 10 separate joins, one for each new column.

Answer (score 0):

I thnk your friend will be [LAG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Here's an implementation:

```
Declare @t table (
    ID int,
    Payment int,
    Yr int
)
Insert Into @t Values(112,0,2004)
Insert Into @t Values(112,0,2005)
Insert Into @t Values(112,0,2006)
Insert Into @t Values(112,9592,2007)
Insert Into @t Values(112,12332,2008)
Insert Into @t Values(112,9234,2011)
Insert Into @t Values(112,5400,2012)
Insert Into @t Values(112,7392,2014)
Insert Into @t Values(112,8321,2015)

Insert Into @t Values(113,0,2009)
Insert Into @t Values(113,9234,2011)
Insert Into @t Values(113,5400,2013)
Insert Into @t Values(113,8321,2015)


;with E1(n) as (Select 1 Union All Select 1 Union All Select 1 Union All Select 1 Union All Select 1 Union All Select 1 Union All Select 1 Union All Select 1 Union All Select 1 Union All Select 1)
,E2(n) as (Select 1 From E1 a, E1 b)
,E4(n) as (Select 1 From E2 a, E2 b)
,E5(n) as (Select row_number() over(order by isnull(null,1)) From E4 a, E1 b)
,IDYears as (
    Select z.ID, Yr = y.n
    From (
        Select 
            Id, 
            MinYear = min(Yr),
            MaxYear = max(Yr)
        From @t a
        Group By Id
        ) z
    Inner Join E5 y On y.n between z.MinYear and z.MaxYear
)

Select 
    *,
    [t-1] = Lag(B.Payment, 1) Over(Partition By a.ID Order By a.Yr),
    [t-2] = Lag(B.Payment, 2) Over(Partition By a.ID Order By a.Yr),
    [t-3] = Lag(B.Payment, 3) Over(Partition By a.ID Order By a.Yr),
    [t-4] = Lag(B.Payment, 4) Over(Partition By a.ID Order By a.Yr),
    [t-5] = Lag(B.Payment, 5) Over(Partition By a.ID Order By a.Yr),
    [t-6] = Lag(B.Payment, 6) Over(Partition By a.ID Order By a.Yr),
    [t-7] = Lag(B.Payment, 7) Over(Partition By a.ID Order By a.Yr),
    [t-8] = Lag(B.Payment, 8) Over(Partition By a.ID Order By a.Yr),
    [t-9] = Lag(B.Payment, 9) Over(Partition By a.ID Order By a.Yr),
    [t-10] = Lag(B.Payment, 10) Over(Partition By a.ID Order By a.Yr)
From IDYears a
Left Join @t b On a.ID = b.ID and a.Yr = b.Yr
Order By A.ID
```